# Richfaces <a4j:ajax> and <rich:popupPanel> "conflict"

Tags: ajax, jsf, netbeans, richfaces, popuppanel

I've stumbled upon a strage behavior of richfaces. Some background about my view structure:

- It's mainly a `<rich:extendedDataTable>` where a click on a row displays info about it on a `<a4j:outputPanel>`
- Also, each row has a context menu with items like "Create", "Edit", etc... that pops a `<rich:popupPanel>`

The component structure is this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:column>
        <rich:dataScroller for="testTable" maxPages="7"/>
        <rich:extendedDataTable id="testTable" value="#{testController.items}" rendered="#{testController.items.rowCount != 0}"
        selection="#{testController.selectedRow}" noDataLabel="No results to show" var="test" rows="20"
        style="width: 790px" selectionMode="single">

            <a4j:ajax execute="@form"
                event="selectionchange" 
                listener="#{testController.selectionListener}"
                render=":res"/>

            {columns to display}

        </rich:extendedDataTable>
    </h:column>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="res">
        <rich:panel header="Selected Rows:" rendered="#{not empty testController.selectedRows}">
            <rich:list type="unordered" value="#{testController.selectedRows}" var="t">
                <h:outputText value="#{t.name}"/>
                <br/>
                <h:outputText value="#{t.details}" converter="#{testConverter}"/>
            </rich:list>
        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:panelGrid>

<rich:contextMenu target="testTable" mode="ajax" id="contextMenu">
    <rich:menuItem label="Edit" render="popupEdit" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popupEdit')}.show();" mode="ajax"/>
</rich:contextMenu>

<rich:popupPanel id="popupEdit" modal="true" autosized="true" resizeable="false" moveable="false" domElementAttachment="form">
    <rich:hotKey key="esc" onkeyup="#{rich:component('popupEdit')}.hide(); return false;"/>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Edit Test"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popupEditar')}.hide(); return false;">
            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/css/images/fechar_janela.png" width="20" height="20"/>
        </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>

    <h:panelGrid id="popupEditContent" columns="2">
        ... {display of info}

            <a4j:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{testeController.update()}" render="tabelaTestes, contextMenu"/>
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <rich:messages ajaxRendered="true" />
            </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

And now the strange behaviour (using NetBeans):

- Deploy the app from NetBeans;
- Open the URL of the deployed project on browser (Firefox) . The `<a4j:ajax>` inlined in the table doesn't work, I know this because the 'testController.selectionListener' is not called and the details are not displayed (it sets the attribute `current` in the backing bean). The contextMenu works but the popupPanel shows null or empty properties in all fields (the `current` attribute is not set);
- Go back to the IDE, remove all the `<rich:popupPanel>` section and save the file;
- Back in the browser, hit F5 and click a row. Now the `<a4j:ajax>` works and calls `testController.selectionListener`, showing the details in `<a4j:outputPanel>`. The context menu works but (obviously) the panel does not pop;
- In the IDE, put back the `<rich:popupPanel>` section and save the file;
- Now refresh the page again, and everything works, details are shown and the Edit pop up shows the right info of the selected row.

I have tried deploying it without the `<rich:popupPanel>` section and the selecionListener gets called. I think that the problem is deploying the page with both `<a4j:ajax>` and `<rich:popupPanel>` sections, hence the "conflict".

1. I took the structure from the richfaces showcase and made changes. I noticed that in the showcase, the `<rich:popupPanel>` is placed outside the `<h:form>` tag, wich in my project is placed in the template.xhtml (so a topmenu page works). Is it possible that the error is caused by this placement?
2. Could this be considered a bug to file in the richfaces project or am I missing something there?
3. Is there a workaround or solution?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** I have solved it. I set the `id` attribute to "form" in the `<h:form>` tag, in template.xhtml, so now it looks like this:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <div id="top" class="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="center_content">
           <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

It was the only change I made and now all the components work at first post-deploy.

Edit: Found the solution when searching for another problem: [JSF  action call on secon click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094615/jsf-a4jcomandbutton-action-call-on-secon-click)