# JSF components ViewState is being lost when I open rich:popupPanel

Tags: jsf, viewstate

I have a rich:popupPanel with content:

```
<rich:popupPanel id = "popupId">
    <h:panelGrid>
        <h:form id="formId">
           <h:panelGrid>
                // content, e.g. radiobuttons, dropdowns, panelGroups and other jsf and   richfaces components , nested components
           </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGrid>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

And a link to open and rerender the form and the popup:

```
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="myListener();" render="popupId formId">
```

I have tried many values of `render` attribute, such as `popupId` or `formId`.

When I click the link, the popup window is being opened but I don't have `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden input field in the form. When I try to select some radio or to change value for dropdown (or any other action), then the first submit does nothing, because the `javax.faces.ViewState` is missing. After that, it reappears back in the form and the second submit and on works fine.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<a4j:comandbutton> action is only invoked on second click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094615/a4jcomandbutton-action-is-only-invoked-on-second-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very easy. Not to ajax-render components with `<h:form>` within.
Put all components inside   and render these components !

```
<rich:popupPanel id="popupId">
    <h:form id="formId">
        <h:panelGrid id="panelGridId">
            // content
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>  
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Not `popupId`, not `formId` !!!!!!!

```
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="someListener()" render="panelGridId" />
```

And then we will not lose `javax.faces.ViewState` id and everything will work correctly!